# How to tell if the occurence of a variable is statistically significant/meaningful?

Tags: statistical-significance, language-models

Since my previous question seems to be unclear, I will try to put it in other words.

I have been working on a child speech corpus, which consists of sentences in which children of various ages verbally explain a specific picture in context. From these sentences, I extract information about explicit path informing lexical items (such as prepositions). According to theoretical claims, for languages that are verb framed (where path information is embedded in the verb) it is unlikely to observe the use of explicit path informing lexical items together with verb, since the verb is expected to include that information within itself. However there is no quantitative specification about the 'unlikeliness of occurrence' that is in mention.

Moving from this introduction, is it possible for me to claim anything statistically meaningful based on the observed percentage of explicit path informing words wrt the whole sample? For example, is there any commonly used minimum threshold percentage value in statistics, such that any occurrence of a variable above that threshold can no longer be considered as unlikely?

In short, what I found is in more than 30% of examples there exists an explicit use of path informing words, which is theoretically absurd since the theory claims the occurrence of such words in verb-framed languages is unlikely. Why I see a contradiction between the theory and observations is that intuitively, 30% seems too high to conclude an unlikeliness. However this is only an intuition, and I need an objective statistical ground to claim that this percentage of occurrence is statistically significant, is not by chance and meaningful.

I first attempted to use T-Test, but then I realized it is for comparing the observation of the same principle in different subjects. I hope this time I put the question clear enough, and someone guide me accordingly.

Comment: Do you have a substantive question that you hope the data can help answer? Eg, if you believe that the % is < some value based on theories of adjective use by children, then we can test this & tell you if its significant or not. OTOH, if you don't have a question, it will be difficult to get the data to provide an answer.

Comment: I rewrote the question, please guide me if you can. Thank you.

Comment: "unlikely" is much too vague to be used as the basis of a test

Comment: I think there is enough here now that something could be said about your situation. But if this gets re-opened, the answer won't be a statistical test. As @Glen_b notes, no test is logically possible in your case.

Comment: A theory that uses vague words such as "unlikely," without otherwise *quantifying* their meaning, is akin to a chemical theory that predicts the temperature of a reaction should be "warm-ish" or a biological theory that predicts warm-blooded flying creatures should be "large-ish."  Such nonquantitative assertions are, at best, pseudo-scientific.  Statistical significance can neither replace nor overcome such deficiencies.

Comment: You could be better off presenting a confidence interval.